# Systemd networking boots with timeout

Tags: networking, systemd

I've a Debian (installed 10, upgrade over time to 12.4) with additional Proxmox packages installed. The systems runs for several months without an issue. Every evening, it stops with `rtcwake` and automatically restarts in the morning. In the background once a week, an auto upgrade runs.

Since some days (I didn't login to the host for several months), the system was not responding via network. During boot it hangs on "networking". I don't use NetworkManager or systemd-networkd.

Via rescue boot, I've set a TimeoutOnStart on the networking service (first 30s, then 300s, now 10s). Then the system comes up, but of course without networking. The error is not very helpful

```
$> journalctl -xeu networking
Defined-By: systemd
Support: https://www.debian.org/support

A start job for unit networking.service has begun execution.

The job identifier is 31.
Dez 17 17:23:17 saturn networking[1269]: networking: Configuring network interfaces
Dez 17 17:28:17 saturn systemd[1]: networking.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
Dez 17 17:28:17 saturn systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=15/TERM
Subject: Unit process exited
Defined-By: systemd
Support: https://www.debian.org/support

An ExecStart= process belonging to unit networking.service has exited.

The process' exit code is 'killed' and its exit status is 15.
Dez 17 17:28:47 saturn systemd[1]: networking.service: State 'final-sigterm' timed out. Killing.
Dez 17 17:28:47 saturn systemd[1]: networking.service: Killing process 1383 (python3) with signal SIGKILL.
Dez 17 17:28:47 saturn systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Subject: Unit failed
```

After logging im, when I start via `systemctl start networking`, the network comes up and works as expected. And it takes around 1s to start the network. I don't understand or find the root cause. Any hints?

Here some additional infos.
We talk about an Onboard-Ethernet eno1 and a simple Proxmox Bridge setting.

```
# /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet manual

iface eno1 inet6 auto

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
    address 192.168.10.2/24
    gateway 192.168.10.254
    bridge-ports eno1
    bridge-stp off
    bridge-fd 0
    dns-nameservers 192.168.10.254
```

I've added the timeout setting, otherwise the system hangs at boot (even waiting for 10mins)

```
# /etc/systemd/system/network-online.target.wants/networking.service
[Unit]
Description=Network initialization
Documentation=man:interfaces(5) man:ifup(8) man:ifdown(8)
DefaultDependencies=no
After=local-fs.target network-pre.target
Before=shutdown.target network.target network-online.target
Conflicts=shutdown.target
Requires=ifupdown2-pre.service
Wants=network.target
After=local-fs.target network-pre.target systemd-sysctl.service systemd-modules-load.service ifupdown2-pre.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
SyslogIdentifier=networking
TimeoutStartSec=10s
TimeoutStopSec=10s
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/networking
ExecStart=/usr/share/ifupdown2/sbin/start-networking start
ExecStop=/usr/share/ifupdown2/sbin/start-networking stop
ExecReload=/usr/share/ifupdown2/sbin/start-networking reload

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target network-online.target
```

As written, NetworkManager is disabled, networkd not installed, it's the classic networking setup (I assume). I didnt find any additional log messages somewhere else.